# Database of images to estimate cloud cover

Tags: data-request, weather, metadata, photographs

Is there any freely available database of sky pictures, which also already has an information about the cloud cover in metadata (by percentage, or by okta)?
I am no meteorologist, but I want to train my program to estimate cloud cover from pictures of sky I will take.
Do you think it makes any sense?
Or do you think it would be better, more precise, to calculate cloud cover from image processing?

Edit: I am looking more for a database of pictures like this - allskycam.com but with the cloud cover already calculated

Answer (score 1):

Data availability has been discussed here:

[Are there open historic cloud cover data files available?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4795/are-there-open-historic-cloud-cover-data-files-available)

I don't know if it is both IR and VIS, but they may link to published analysis methods that include ML techniques.

Comment: thank you for your reply, maybe I should move this question into the opendata section... I am looking more for a database of pictures like this - http://allskycam.com/ but with the cloud cover already calculated